# php ajax auto refresh smoothing

Tags: php, ajax

The code is working fine, but since the function refreshes every 2 seconds, the image blinks abruptly and goes off. How can I make it look smooth or not make it blink?

```
echo '<script>
window.setInterval(function() {
    yopahshareloader("'.$id.'"," '.$postype.'");
}, 2000);
</script>';

//the code calling the ajax function.
echo "<img onclick='respond(";
echo '"yo","' . $id . '"' . ',"' . $postype . '"';
echo " )' src='images/icons/yo.png' style='margin-bottom:5px;'/>";
```

Comment: Please also show the methods yopahshareloader() and respond()... Is there any framework like jQuery available? Possible solution is to fadeOut the current image and at the same time fadeIn the new image...

Comment: respond is just a database count incrementar function. the yopahshareloader function is the actual ajax function which is being called at 2seconds interval. the image doesnt change, only the count beside it will change. yet the whole image reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a little unclear, so I'll assume the image blinks because it's changing?

Firstly google & searching stackoverflow will usually help you get your answer but here's what you're looking for.

You want load the image then display it, so what you can do is load it into javascript, bind an event for when it loads, and then do your magic :P

```
//create image object
var image = new Image();

//add image path
image.src = "";

//bind load event
image.onload = function(){
    //now load next image
    // The image has loaded
}
```

So now you've stopped the blinking, you could look into using jQuery to allow for a fadeIn and fadeOut effect.

Comment: image is not changing. the number beside it may change. do we have a selector in js, where only when something in db changes, our element gets refreshed?

Comment: If you could supply more of what you're doing by editing your original post I'd be able to help and perhaps others may too. I'm not sure why it's flickering if you're not editing that element.